# Transit visa for KBP Ukraine if I am travelling to London

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, ukraine

Do I need transit visa for Ukraine, I am travelling from India to London via Kiev airport? I am an Indian passport holder.

Answer (score 3):

From Timatic, the system used by airlines:

“Visa required.

Transiting without a visa is possible for:

Passengers transiting through Kiev (KBP) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

TWOV does not apply when transiting between terminals D and F.”

https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b